# Jquery fullcalendar not showing events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using jquery fullcalendar on one of my view pages for an MVC project to show events.

But it doesn't show the events
here is my code:

```
public class HighlightMonthlyEvents
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public long EventStartDate { get; set; }
        public long EventEndDate { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }

        public HighlightMonthlyEvents()
        {
        }
    }

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult HighlightCalendar()
    {
        var tasksList = new List<HighlightMonthlyEvents>();

        tasksList.Add(new HighlightMonthlyEvents
        {
            id = 1,
            EventName = "Google search",
            EventStartDate = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now),
            EventEndDate = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4)),
            url = "www.google.com"
        });
        tasksList.Add(new HighlightMonthlyEvents
        {
            id = 1,
            EventName = "Bing search",
            EventStartDate = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)),
            EventEndDate = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(4)),
            url = "www.bing.com"
        });

        var highlightDays = Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.ExportToString(tasksList.ToArray());

        return Json(highlightDays, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        // FullCalendar
        alert("Helo");
        $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'today prev,next',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            editable: false,
            events: function (callback) {
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        $.getJSON("/Test/HighlightCalendar/", null,
               function (result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    for (i in result) {
                        var calEvent = result[i];
                        alert(calEvent.id);
                        calEvent.eventStartDate = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.eventStartDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                        calEvent.eventEndDate = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.eventEndDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                    }
                }

                var calevents = result;
                // then, pass the CalEvent array to the callback
                callback(calevents);

               });
            }

        });
```

my json object returns :

```
[{"id":1,"eventName":"Google search","eventStartDate":1279745050,"eventEndDate":1279759450,"url":"www.google.com"},

{"id":1,"eventName":"Bing search","eventStartDate":1279831450,"eventEndDate":1279845850,"url":"www.bing.com"}]
```

alert(calEvent.id) says undefined...

Please help me!

Thanks a Lot!
Anusha

Answer (score 3):

You should be using events keys (key: value pair) that match the fullCalendar [event object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)... e.g. instead of `eventName`, use `title` and use `start` instead of `eventStartDate`.

Look at the event object link to find all the keys you should be using.

Oh, and the id's need to be unique.

Edit: Oh and you could be using the [event sources](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/eventSources/) instead of getJson.